# How Does Windows Know Which Messages Belong to Which Process?

Tags: c++, windows, events, input, kernel

Does Windows know which messages belong to each specific window (if so how does it know?) or does it just send the messages in general and it is up to the application to grab the messages it needs?

Thank you all for the replies. I do love it when someone votes it down without explaining.

Comment: Each message is destined for a window. Look at the `MSG` members.

Comment: @chris So how does it know which message belongs to which Window. If for example you click a certain area how does it know the click belongs or doesn't to a certain Window?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details, but I mean there is a `WindowFromPoint` function. Maybe it uses that. I presume whatever internal data it keeps provides an efficient way of determining this information.

Answer (score 0):

Even these advanced, 64-bit days, a Windows application still, ultimately, at some deep, dark point, still consists of a window message processing loop. A process' main message "pump" is responsible for pullling messages out of the queue and directing them to the proper window via (typically() the hWnd parameter of the SendMessage API - the very first parameter to the method.

Within an application, something like a click event eventually gets translated as a message to  a window, and if that window decides not to handle the message, passes it up the chain of parent windows until one opts, based on the other parameters, to process it. Alternatively, the window recipient of a message may make explicit notification to a parent window, WM_PARENT_NOTIFTY that a message *it* just received caused something to happen that the parent should know about. As an example, think of how changing a color in a color picker dialog could require its parent to be notified that a color change had been made. There are myriad such chained dependencies in most apps that explains a lot of the orchestrations your talking about.

Obviously, to get to the proper window handler to receive, say, something like a mouse click, a low-level system handler has to figure out where the mouse was when it was clicked, and the window manager has to translate that point to the window highest in the z-order to make the inference that window was part of the active app at the time the mouse was clicked - ultimately making that app and that window the target of the "WM_CLICK" message.

That's a fairly simplistic illustration, and I'm sure there are probably relevant details (potholes? :) ) I'm omitting, but I think it offers a picture of the basic question being posed. I hope that helps some.

Comment: I figured it had to do with coordinates z index as you say and which window had focus at the time of the click and I am sure it also knows the coordinates for the position of the window as well, otherwise how would it know that the mouse was inside that window.